# How to avoid re-rendering when i pass an object as prop to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have parent component with multiple child components. Different types of data will be passed to child components after getting data from api. Some of the components will get object as a prop. I am trying to avoid rerenders in that component. Even if the data is same it is rerendering. How can i avoid this rerenders?

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [childData, setChildData] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = getChildData();
    setChildData(data);
  }, [])

  return (
      <Child data={childData}/>
  );
};

const Child = React.memo((props) => {
  const {name, email} = props.data;
  return (
      <div>
        <p>Name: {name}</p>
        <p>Email: {email}</p>
      </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: You should take a look at memoization : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: Here's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705867/prevent-re-render-on-a-purecomponent-when-passing-an-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per React Official Docs, By default React will only shallowly compare complex objects in the props object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide a custom comparison function as the second argument. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo. Here is an example.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [childData, setChildData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const data = getChildData();
        setChildData(data);
    }, [])

    return (
        <Child data={childData} />
    );
};

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
    return prevProps.name == nextProps.name && prevProps.email == nextProps.email;
}
const Child = React.memo((props) => {
    const { name, email } = props.data;
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Name: {name}</p>
            <p>Email: {email}</p>
        </div>
    );
}, areEqual);
```

Answer (score 2):

By default [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) will only `shallowly compare` complex objects in the `props`.

You can use **custom equality check of props**. Pass the custom check function as second argument to `React.memo` similar to below

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  const {name, email} = prevProps.data;
  const {name: nextName, email: nextEmail} = nextProps.data;
  return name === nextName && email === nextEmail;
};

const Child = React.memo((props) => {...}, areEqual);
```

For more details check [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely).